# Which of the following functions decreases in the interval $(0,1)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, derivatives, graphing-functions

[image]

> The function $f(x)$ is graphed in the interval $(0,1).$  Which of the following functions decreases in the interval $(0,1)$ ?

My attempt:

The function $f(x)$ is increasing in the interval $(0,1)$. So,I think $A,D$ and $E$ are incorrect. Here, I'm stuck.If $f(x)$ is increasing in the interval $(0,1)$, is this imply $f'(x)$ is also increasing in the interval $(0,1)$ ?

Comment: Sketch $f'(x)$ on a piece of paper. Is it increasing? Decreasing?

Comment: @Arthur but, I dont know, what is $f(x)$ ?

Comment: Can I use $f(x)=  \sqrt x ?$

Comment: I didn't say draw $f'(x)$. I said sketch it. Don't care about exact values. Just about the general shape. Where does $f'$ have large values? Where does it have small values? You don't need a functional expression for that. You can do that just by looking at the graph. At least that's something you ought to be able to do.

Comment: For (E). If $f$ is strictly increasing and $x',x,f(x'),f(x)$ are all in the domain of $f, $ then with $y'=f(x')$ and $y=f(x)$ we have $x'>x\implies f(x')>f(x)\implies y'>y\implies f(y')>f(y)\implies f(f(x'))>f(f(x)).$

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

Using the graph, we can say that

$$f'(0)>1$$
and
$$f'(1)<1$$

thus, $f'$ seems to decrease.
The answer should be $B$.